# Problema con renderizar columnas en vertical en Laravel PHP

Tags: html, laravel

Estoy imprimiendo una lista de datos en un formulario con un foraech en laravel, quiero que se muestre en varias columnas, xq es larga, Xfavor

```
@foreach($datos as $dato)
    <tr>
       <td>
          {{ $datos->name }}
    </td>
   </tr>
 @endforeach
```

[image: imagen]

Comment: ya agregue una imagen

Comment: Gracias ya con eso lo resolví ☺️

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera.

En el controlador en la función dónde envío la vista, guarde en la variable chunk los datos separados x el método chunk() y luego envié esa variable a la vista

```
$datos = Datos::all();
$chunk = $datos->chunk(4);
Return view(datos.create,compact('chunk'));
```

En la vista

```
@foreach($chunk as datos)
   <div class="row">
       @foreach($datos as $dato)
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <span class="col-md-3">{{  $dato->name }}</span>
          </div>
       @endforeach 
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Y listo, funcionó, gracias ☺️ disculpen si no redacto bien, es mi primera vez x aqui